# Can we append an element to a list in scala, and also to tuple in scala?

Tags: list, scala, tuples

Can an element be appended to a list in Scala, for example, I have a list i.e.,
`var li = List (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`
can I append `6` to the list, if so how?

In case of tuple how can I append, for example,
`var tu = (1, "Hi", 20000)`
can I append the `"Hello"` string to it?

Answer (score 2):

Both `List` and `Tuple` are immutable constructs so to append or prepend an element, you create a new `List`/`Tuple`.

```
val oldLst = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val newLst = oldLst :+ 6
```

Appending to a `List` is a linear operation, O(n). It's much more efficient when prepending.

```
val fromZero = 0 :: newLst
```

Scala 3 offers enhanced `Tuple` abilities not available in earlier Scala releases.

```
val threeTup = (1, "Hi", 20000)
val fourTup  = threeTup ++ "Hello" *: EmptyTuple
```

Note: Experienced Scala practitioners *never* use `var`.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: val threeTup = (1, "Hi", 20000)
val fourTup  = threeTup ++ "Hello" *: EmptyTuple ...

Can't perform this, it gives an error saying "value ++ is not a member of (Int, String, Int)"